# How to host Neo4j with Frames on Rexster

Tags: neo4j, tinkerpop, rexster

Does anyone know how to host a "Tinkerpop Rexster" server and communicate with "Tinkerpop Frames" ?
This is the only page I have found and it does not help.
https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/tree/master/rexster-kibbles/frames-kibble

Any links and suggestions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The Frames Kibble simply takes your existing Frames code and exposes all `@Property` annotations through a REST Service call.  The example at the very bottom of the wiki page you reference pretty much tells the story:

```
http://localhost:8182/graphs/tinkergraph/vertices/1/tp/frames/person
```

would find the vertex with an identifier of “1”, wrap the returned vertex in a Person frame, and utilize the @Property Frames annotations to “get” a Person object as JSON. The JSON would look like this:

```
{
  "name":"marko",
  "age":29,
  "version":"0.3",
  "queryTime":24.40612
}
```

This Rexster Extension never really kept up with the development of Frames itself as there was not much interest from the community.  As such, it's not super useful except for this simple feature.

If you are using Frames and want to use it within Rexster, I'd say that the better method would be to call your Frames from the Gremlin Extension (or via RexPro).  In that way you get full access to all aspects of what Frames offers.  You might use Frames within the context of a custom DSL as described [here](http://thinkaurelius.com/2013/07/25/developing-a-domain-specific-language-in-gremlin/)